# What is "Joker card" to be used in IPL?

Tags: cricket, terminology, officiating, strategy, indian-premier-league

In IPL 2014, Team owners will be able to use there Joker card. Whatever I have read and searched I found that teams can use joker card at time of auction to retain there previous players playing for Team?

What is actually "Joker Card"? Each team can get how many Joker card? What is limit of using.

Answer (score 3):

"Joker Cards" is a new strategy for teams to retain their players in the team. Using joker cards they can retain more players than previous auctions. A team can retain a player after he is purchased (i.e. successfully bid) by other team.

#### How will it work?

Each team will be given some numbers of joker cards (probably three). They can use them to retain their players after the player's bid is completed and purchased by other team. E.g. Bangalore has successfully bid for Dwayne Smith, who played for Mumbai last season. If Mumbai doesn't want to let him go, they can use a joker card and retain him in the team. But the only different is that they have to pay him his current market rate (by which Bangalore had bid for him.).

#### What are pros?

- A team can now retain more players than previous auctions.
- A player can be retained by his current market rate (either higher or less or same).

#### What are cons?

- A team won't have more options to bid for other players.
- A team has to return a player even after a successful bid.

Answer (score 1):

> The new rule introduced this year- Right to Match- will provide teams
>   an opportunity in the 2014 auction to get one or more player from
>   their previous year’s squad depending on how many players they have
>   retained prior to auction.
>
> This means Mumbai Indians can exercise this right only once as they
>   have retained 5 players whereas Delhi Daredevils can exercise right to
>   match three times.  Franchise can exercise this right in following
>   manner
>
> This right can only be exercised on a player who was part of the
>   franchise in the IPL 2013 If such a player is sold to any other team
>   in the process of auction-  the auctioneer, before completing process
>   of auction for that player, will ask relevant franchise  if they want
>   to exercise “Right  to Match”. If Franchise chooses to exercise their
>   right to match they will get the player at the final bid amount made
>   for the player in the process of auction. However franchise is can
>   only take upto 4 capped Indian player by combination of retention
>   advance to auction and Right to Match.
>
> How Right to Match will be beneficial to the Franchise? Franchises
>   were allowed to retain upto 5 players prior to auction. However this
>   retention came at the fixed price decided by IPL management.
>   Aggressive bidding for a player often increases his bid price very
>   high. Right to match allows Franchise to retain player without taking
>   part in bid process and if they think that bid price is good to buy
>   such player. This also creates continuity as teams get a player who
>   has previously played for them and whose strength and weaknesses they
>   know very well.
>
> Since Chennai Super Kings have already retained 4 Indian capped player
>   they will not have any right to match for capped Indian player however
>   they can use it for foreign player played for them in 2013.

Source: [Joker Card/ Right to Match](http://www.smashreport.com/posts/show_article/IPL-2014-new-auction-rule-RIGHT-TO-MATCH---Joker-Card-1102)

Comment: -1 for plagiarism. For future reference, it is recommended to (block)quote where necessary to distinguish between sourced content and original content. See [this](https://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/190/use-of-quotes-in-answers) for more information. Also, see this for more information: https://meta.sports.stackexchange.com/questions/221/original-answer-or-not